# Excel VBA: Find out size of foreign lookup table

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA sub that (among other things) pastes a lookup formula into some cells.  The lookup formula is presently of the form

```
LOOKUP(RC5,lookup.xlsx!Item,lookup.xlsx!R2C:R559C)
```

but the size of the lookup table will change.  Is there a good way to find the size of the lookup table, that is, the last row?

In a pinch I suppose I could open the lookup file (what's the command for that?) and do

```
Windows("lookup.xlsx").Activate
last = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row    
Windows("whatever.xlsx").Activate
```

but I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the last used cell has a bad reputation in Excel AFAIK. See for example [this](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/lastcell.htm) , although a bit outdated. If you can, just be sure to insert an EOF value in the last used row and scan for it.

**Edit**

Remember:

- A null value (or spaces) may serve well as an EOF flag. Be sure to be consistent.
- You may always include full columns in the lookup range and excel will take care of the end (if there are no more used cells under your range. Like in =LOOKUP(A1,C:C,D:D)

Comment: So is the best way to have Excel open the file, then?

Comment: No chance of an EOF tag, by the way; others will have the file in question and I can only hope the sheet remains sensible.

Comment: Wait, does that LOOKUP(A1,C:C,D:D) actually work?  Cool!  Will headers in row 1 cause problems?

Comment: @Charles The headers may affect the results if they contain values that can be looking for in the LOOKUP. In that case, you may tray something like LOOKUP(A1,C2:C10000,D2:D10000)

Comment: I think Excel's lookup fails when the range is too large -- it finds a value in the middle, sees that it's blank, and ends.

Comment: @Charles Nope. Tested with =LOOKUP(A1,C$2:C10000,D$2:D10000) and works ok